# How to use @angular/animations in angular asp.net core 2 template?

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular-material

I can't import `@angular/animations` in app.module.shared file:
[image]
When i import `@angular/animations` in app.module.browser file animations don't work.

What i need to do for use material animations in angular asp.net core 2 template?

Comment: You have to import from `@angular/platform-browser/animations` for `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAmimationsModule` for no animations.

Comment: @Edric I imported the BrowserAnimationsModule module into the files app.module.browser and app.module.shared. When i import a module in the file app.module.shared, an error occurs.  When i import a module in the file app.module.browser, the animations do not work.

Comment: What's your full error stacktrace? Post it somewhere.

Comment: @Edric http://dropmefiles.com/P4sFz html file with full error

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't troubleshoot your issue without actual code.

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I initially added the animations import into the app.module.shared file and I got the same error. To fix it I moved the import into the app.module.browser file.

This is how I left my module.browser:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.module.shared';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppModuleShared
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

Example of using BrowserAnimationsModule:
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/commit/c0c47e3def208873c470a524a826f8d235a5f9de

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted is caused because`@angular/animations` uses DOM references, like **document** and **window**.

By default, ASP.NET Core MVC SPA apps created using the initial template will pre-render your Javascript code on serverside, as defined in your Index view.

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

So you can't add DOM references on server and shared modules.

You have to add @angular/animation to `app.module.browser.ts` and then use it on your submodules and/or components.